# How to change buttons color on click of button in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, button, ionic4, background-color

I want to change buttons color on click of button.

I am creating a quiz application.

On click of a button if the answer is correct the color should be changed to green and if wrong it should be changed to red.

This is worked. I have done this.

But now the issue is if the answer is wrong then its color changed to red and correct answers button color changed to green.

How to do this?

**play-quiz.html**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-row class="marginTop">
      <ion-col class="border ion-text-center">
        Grand Central Terminal, Park Avenue, New York is the world's
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="marginTop">
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-button id="1" #first class="btn" expand="block" (click)="onClick(first,'1')">
          Largest Railway Station
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-button id="2" #second class="btn" expand="block" (click)="onClick(second,'2')">
          highest railway station
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-button id="3" #third class="btn" expand="block" (click)="onClick(third,'3')">
          longest railway station
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-button id="4" #four class="btn" expand="block" (click)="onClick(four,'4')">
          None of the above
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button class="btn right" expand="small">
          Next
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-list>
```

**play-quiz.ts**.

```
answer: any = "1";

onClick(ionicButton, btn: any) {
      if(this.answer == btn){
        ionicButton.color =  'success';
      } else {
        ionicButton.color =  'danger';
      }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use [ngClass] for the same. Based on a global property (which is to be changed after click event) you can add the desired class to the button element.

Comment: can you please explain it with example. I am new to ionic. I am learning it. @AnoopRajasekharaWarrier

Answer (score 2):

In HTML:

```
<ion-button [ngClass]="isClicked() ? 'btn red': 'btn'" (click)="onClick()">Toggle</ion-button>
```

In TS:

```
isClick: boolean=false;

isClicked(){
 return this.isClick;
}

onClick(){
 this.isClick=!this.isClick;
}
```

The functionality you can modify in `onClick()` method. Based on the value `isClicked()` returned it will append the class 'red' (if it returns true, it will add, else no).

CSS you can all the required styles.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this from below CSS code:

```
ion-button:focus {
        --background: #067856;
        --color: white;
      }
```