# How to manage lots of buttons in ionic?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am building this app with surveys. Users need to answer it by clicking **Yes** and **No** button. Once the user clicks/taps the answer the button should turn to blue color and the other button should retain its default look. The issue is, when I tapped one (1) button, the other buttons also changes its color to blue instead of staying to its default look. I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929233/how-to-change-buttons-color-on-click-of-button-in-ionic-4) solution to change the color of button when user clicks it. But the issue occurs that all buttons turn to blue when click. Hope you can help me, I am newbie in learning ionic, and everything is new to me.

**The image below is the default look of the button**

[image]

This should be the proper look, once the user taps the answer, the answer is the one with blue background. But when user taps the button, the two buttons turns to blue.

[image]

Here are my codes:

**.html**

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size-md = "6">
      <ion-button id = "q1-yes-on" [ngClass]= "isClicked('q1-yes-on') ? 'btn-pressed' : 'btn-unpressed'" id = "q1-yes-off" (click) = "onClick('q1-yes-off')" fill = "clear">
        <div class = "parentElement">
          <img src = "{{myYesImage|staticpath}}"/>
          <br><br><p class = "btn-work"><b>Yes</b></p>
        </div>
      </ion-button> 
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col> 
      <ion-button id = "q2-yes-on" [ngClass]= "isClicked('q2-yes-on') ? 'btn-pressed' : 'btn-unpressed'" id= "q2-yes-off" (click) = "onClick('q2-yes-off')" fill = "clear">
        <div class = "parentElement">
          <img  src = "{{myNoImage|staticpath}}"/>
          <br><br><p class = "btn-work"><b>No</b></p>
        </div>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

**.ts**

```
     isClick: boolean = false;

     private _id: string;

       isClicked(_id){
           console.log(_id);
           return this.isClick

 
        } 

     onClick(_id){
              console.log(_id);
              this.isClick=!this.isClick;
      }
```

Comment: when either button is clicked, it changes isClick to true. Both ion-button's ngClass will be affected by this.

Comment: @joohong89 how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

use an unique variable for each group of buttons. This variable can get three values, e.g. `null`,`true` and `false` -you can also choose thre another values, e.g. `-1`,`0` and `1` or `0`, `1` and `2`

```
<button (click)="variable=variable!==true?true:null"
    [style.background-color]="variable===true?'blue':null">
     yes
</button>
<button (click)="variable=variable!==false?false:null"
    [style.background-color]="variable===false?'blue':null">
    false
</button>
```

Well, you has a list of buttons, so imagine you has a loop over an array of objects "questions". So, make that the "variable" was a property of each object. Imagine an array of questions like

```
questions=[
           {text:"2+2 is equal 4",response:null},
           {text:"2+2 is equal 5",response:null}
            ...
]
```

So -see that it's the same code than first, only replace "variable" by "question.response"

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
    {{question.text}}
    <button (click)="question.response=question.response!==true?true:null"
        [style.background-color]="question.response===true?'blue':null">
         yes
    </button>
    <button (click)="question.response=question.response!==false?false:null"
        [style.background-color]="question.response===false?'blue':null">
          false
    </button>
</div>
```

NOTE: you see that there're no code in .ts -only need declare the variables-, see also you can know what are the response writing

```
<pre>
{{questions|json}}
</pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am still bit confuse to apply to my codes

Comment: I change the background using `[style.background-color]`, you can use `[ngClass]="question.response===true?'btn-pressed':'btn-unpressed'"`. I suppose you has any kind of `*ngFor` in your code or store in a variable the value of the response. The idea in Angular or in ionic is the same. You has a variable that change the value and use this variable to change the `[ngClass]`

Answer (score 0):

If have multiple question and answers like you mentioned in your question..  I would suggest you to go with ionic radio groups. so that you don't need to manage anything user cant select multiple answers. you just need to manage the button styling ion radion group will let you know which option user has selected and it will add active class itself. you just need to apply css accordingly which I guess you can manage easily